# Cron stops the script if the file is not found

Tags: shell, cron, zsh

I have the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

a() {
  echo 1
}

a

b() {
  for file in "${DOWNLOADS}"123_*; do
    mv "${file}" "${DOWNLOADS}321"
  done
}

b

c() {
  echo 2
}

c
```

it is executable and if I call it from the terminal it works exactly right: *a, b, c*. But if I try to execute it via *cron* and there is no "*123_{something}*" file in the "*${DOWNLOADS}*" directory, then only function *a* is executed, and the beginning of the foor loop. Function *c* is not called because the script stops.

```
crontab -l
```

=>

```
10 20 * * * zsh /user/file
```

Debugging showed the following:

```
10 20 * * * zsh /user/file >> ~/tmp/cron.txt 2>&1
```

=>

```
+/user/file:47> a
+a:1> echo 1
1
+/user/file:67> b
file:12: no matches found: /Users/ivan/Downloads/123_*
```

As can be seen the execution of the script stopped immediately after the file was not found.

I don't understand why the execution of this script via *cron* stops if the file is not found, and how this can be avoided; can anyone explain this?

Or maybe it's just the limitations of my environment?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you've got a script with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, but you're invoking it with `zsh`. Perhaps you need to check what zsh options are active in your (cron) environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why the execution of this script via cron stops if the file is not found, and how this can be avoided; can anyone explain this?

Using globs that don't match anything is an error:

```
% print nope*
zsh: no matches found: nope*
```

You can fix this by setting the `null_glob` option:

```
% setopt null_glob
% print nope*
[no output, as nothing was found]
```

You can set this for a single pattern by adding `(N)` to the end:

```
% print nope*(N)
```

So in your example, you end up with something like:

```
b() {
  for file in ${DOWNLOADS}123_*(N); do
    mv $file ${DOWNLOADS}321
  done
}
```

---

*NOTE*: this only applies to zsh; in your script you have `#!/bin/sh` at the top, but you're running it with zsh. It's best to change that to `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` if you plan on using zsh.

In standard /bin/sh, it behaves different: a pattern that doesn't match gets replaced by the pattern itself:

```
% sh
$ echo nope*
nope*
```

In that case, you need to check if `$file` in the loop matches `nope*` and continue if it does. But you're running zsh so it's not really applicable: just be aware that /bin/sh and zsh behave quite different with the default settings (you can also get the same behaviour in zsh if you want with `setopt no_nomatch`).